# I can't play movies on windows 10 after an upgrade from win7

Tags: windows-10, video, freeze, display-driver

Youtube is working and Streaming software like stremio or PopcornTime also works.
But when I try to play video files it doesn't work. The computer freezes I get strange colorful squares on the screen. There are player that works better than others: BS.Player is the worst, VLC is better. But eventually all the players doesn't work and the computer freezes or the video has some colorful dots\lines.

If the computer doesn't freeze I get a message about the graphic card that crashed and recovered and about an application that got blocked from using the G.Card

[Dxdiag file](http://www.filedropper.com/dxdiag_17)

I use ATI AMD HD 5700 G.Card.
I tried all kinds of drivers and still nothing.

I'm sure that this connected to the driver cause when I disable it all the things work but I don't have support for more that one screen and the resolution of the movies are bad..

Anyone has any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Ive read a lot of success of running [DDU](http://www.wagnardmobile.com/) while in safe mode and installing the [353.62](http://www.nvidia.com/download/Find.aspx?lang=de-de)  driver. This has worked with some people with the card. On Reddit and Nvidia Website. I would give it a shot.

Comment: But my video card is not nvidia its AMD...Why would I install an nvidia driver

Comment: In your DxDiag this information is in there. `Card name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970
       Manufacturer: NVIDIA
          Chip type: GeForce GTX 970`

Comment: It wasn't a correct file Now I fixed it you can look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If the computer doesn't freeze I get a message about the graphic card that crashed and recovered and about an application that got blocked from using the G.Card

It simply means that graphic card is not supported by your hardware, try to uninstall it and reboot the system. Then navigate to manufacturer's website and install a relevant one for Windows 10. 
Many of most manufacturer's don't support windows 10 fully yet, so best of luck.

> Youtube is working and Streaming software like stremio or PopcornTime also works. But when I try to play video files it doesn't work.

It means that the problem is not related to memory. If the above solution doesn't work for you, try installing Daum's Pot Player. It's extremely light weight (not my opinion but a fact).

Comment: As I already wrote, I tried all kind of drivers including the one that supports win10.

I never said that the problem related to memory. Maybe you meant that the problem is related to memory? Is vlc a light player?

Comment: VLC is not a light player, It's very good and flexible but it faces problems with windows 10 apparently as many other video players. Try Daum Player, it's as better as VLC. And When I said problem is not related to memory I meant that the applications on graphic card are not allocated enough memory by your RAM -- a possible reason for crash.

Comment: I don't think that its a memory problem I have 12GB RAM And I don't see any unusual memory usage in Task MAnager

Comment: Which graphic card are ya using

Comment: So the player works very good :)
But what is the source of the problem?

Comment: Glad to know it worked, as far as I can tell it could be graphic card problem most probably, windows 10 has a hard time integrating memory sectors of graphic card. Size of RAM, is not relevant here. Probably.